# How can I wire a switch into an extension cord?

Tags: wiring, switch, extension-cord

i am trying to make a extension cord with a kill switch in the middle thats going to be mounted to my desk, the cord has red(phase), black(neutral) and green(earth) wires, but the light switch has loop, 1, 2 and common holes, what wires go where?

Comment: When asking questions like this please say what country you are in. Practices vary considerablly round the world.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

**Improper Electrical Wiring** constitutes a serious life safety hazard. It can be the source of structural fire and potentially fatal shocks.

I am not saying that you can't splice a common electrical wall switch into an extension cord. I am saying that it is not a good general practice.

**Consider Instead**

1. Installing a suitable hardwired outlet and wall mounted switch using techniques suited for permanent installation in the structure.
2. Alternatively, consider using a listed extension chord with an integral switch such as [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000KKND86) or [that](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003XK7K8Y).

Comment: This is a great answer.